# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Project.django_apscheduler_djangojob' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django

I am learning django-apscheduler on the window system, And used python manage.py showmigrations command in terminal
but the result is 'django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Project.django_apscheduler_djangojob' doesn't exist")'
My DB setting

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Product', # 数据库名称，
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # 主机地址
        'USER': 'root', # 数据库用户
        'PASSWORD': 'password', # 密码
        'PORT': 3306 # mysql的端口默认3306
    }
}
```

Please help me, Thank you a lot

Comment: It seems you didn't migrate when included library. python manage.py migrate

Answer (score -1):

Run **python manage.py migrate** and restart server